# Extract map data from specific map or tiles?

Tags: azerothcore

Is it possible to extract and assemble map data from specific map IDs or ADTs? Having to extract ALL map data because I edited a single chunk of a single ADT is very frustrating. Especially when dealing with some pathing issues on a custom map that I'm trying to fix.

- I tried removing all patches from the client folder, except my custom one.
- I also tried leaving the default patches empty.
- I tried editing dbc files to only contain my custom map.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.